# Change database in db.Context file dynamically in run time DB first approach ASP.net MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi i want to change database name  dynamically in db.context file in asp.net mvc.I am passing database name dynamically in db.context file. It is working but once i refresh the edmx file means my dynamic coding is automatically cleared in db.context file. i want to change database dynamically in run time in asp.net mvc. Here  i tried in db.context file its working but once i update or refresh the edmx means it clear my code.

My Connection string code in web.config file

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CRMEntities" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.0.73\SQLEXPRESS,14330;Initial Catalog=CRM;User ID=sa;Password=wafewin;
        MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

My Coding in db.context file

MyCRM

```
namespace CostToWafe
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class CRMEntities : DbContext
    {

        public CRMEntities() : base()
        {
            this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = "Presist Security Info=False;User ID =sa;Password=**"+GLOBAL.ZDATABASE+"**;Intial Catalog=SS1718;Data Soure=192.168.70.41";
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AddressType> AddressTypes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Area> Areas { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Bank> Banks { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ContactType> ContactTypes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In this **GLOBAL.ZDATABASE** i pass the database name dynamically in run time. Its working but one i update or fresh edmx file means this code is cleared automatically.

My Controller code

Visitors form Controller

```
public class VisitorsFormController : Controller
{
    CRMEntities db = new CRMEntities();
    // GET: /VisitorsForm/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View()
    }
}
```

Now my doubt is it possible to connect multiple database dynamically in db.context file or any other place without change in web.config file in run time

Any one please help me to resolve this issue to change database name dynamically in db.context file and connect in controller and also please tell another method to change database dynamically in run time mvc .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Expand the edmx file node. You will see a file that has the same name as the entity but ends in .Context.tt. This is the T4 template that is run when you save the EDMX. This T4 template then creates the context. You can modify the T4 template (make sure you have the original in source control or a copy) to generate custom code as needed. You could also create a customer constructor here to do pass in the variable to the string and then pass the database name in at instantiation.

FYI, Consider using string.Format as a method to add the database name into the connection string. Concatenation is expensive, but mainly it's easy to mess something up more when concatenating than with string.Format.